How can I install from GNU ELPA?
I'm trying to install cursor-undo on GNU ELPA, I just get:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not find package cursor-undo. Updating recip...")
  error("Could not find package %S. Updating recipe reposit..." cursor-undo (org-elpa melpa gnu-elpa-mirror nongnu-elpa el-get emacsmirror-mirror))
  straight--convert-recipe(cursor-undo nil)
  straight-use-package(cursor-undo)
  (progn (straight-use-package 'cursor-undo) (defvar use-package--warning324 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "*use-package*")) (goto-char (point-max)) (insert "-----\n" msg "\n\n(use-package cursor-undo :ensure t)\n\n  -->\n\n(use...") (emacs-lisp-mode)) (setq msg (concat msg " (see the *use-package* buffer)")) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (let ((now (current-time))) (message "%s..." "Loading package cursor-undo") (prog1 (if (not (require 'cursor-undo nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'cursor-undo) :error)) (let ((elapsed (float-time ...))) (if (> elapsed 0.1) (message "%s...done (%.3fs)" "Loading package cursor-undo" elapsed) (message "%s...done" "Loading package cursor-undo"))))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning324 :catch err))))
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  #<subr eval-last-sexp>(nil)
  apply(#<subr eval-last-sexp> nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)


I don't have problems installing (use-package sketch-mode :ensure t) which is also supposed to be on GNU ELPA.
Any pointers as to what this can be?
I'm using straight.el with use-package
EDIT: The value of (print package-archives) 
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/") ("nongnu" . "https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/"))

EDIT2: I have package-refresh-contents
ad-handle-definition: ‘url-cache-extract’ got redefined
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Package refresh done
Contacting host: elpa.nongnu.org:443
Package refresh done


What's the output of (print package-archives) ?

Refresh the package contents with M-x package-refresh-contents and then try to install the package.

Try (use-package cursor-undo :ensure t) after running M-x package-refresh-contents.

Also, please add a comment tagging me after updating your post. Otherwise, I won't be notified.

ok, I've tried that and it's still the same. This is so weird. Are there any other packages that are only on GNU ELPA that I can try to verify that it's something specific with GNU ELPA?

From your debug trace message

(progn (straight-use-package 'cursor-undo) (de....

it looks to me like a problem caused by "straight.el" instead of an issue caused by a standard Emacs installation flow.  I tested several times with several Emacs versions using a fresh user account on Linux (each time I removed the whole ~/.emacs.d) and it works well:
(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'cursor-undo)
(cursor-undo)

Would you like to install it without using "straight.el" ?
